# UITextView - How to remain cursor after hide keyboard

Tags: cursor, uitextview

I'm trying to make a UITextView that user could input text and emoticons.

And I got a problem with the cursor displaying.

My goal is to make the cursor appears as normal while selecting emoticon(Keyboard is hidden).

I know it could be done because a app called "Kakao Story" have the feature.

Does anybody have a solution about it?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to make keyboardView hidden to access my purpose.

Here is the code

```
+ (void)hideKeyboard
{
    for (UIWindow *aWindow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {

        for (UIView *possibleKeyboard in [aWindow subviews]) {
            UIView *keyboardView = [self getPeripheralHostViewFromView:possibleKeyboard];
            if (keyboardView) {
                [keyboardView setHidden:YES];
            }
        }
    }
}

+ (void)unhideKeyboard
{
    for (UIWindow *aWindow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {

        for (UIView *possibleKeyboard in [aWindow subviews]) {
            UIView *keyboardView = [self getPeripheralHostViewFromView:possibleKeyboard];
            if (keyboardView) {
                [keyboardView setHidden:NO];
            }
        }
    }
}

+ (UIView *)getPeripheralHostViewFromView:(UIView *)superView
{
    if ([superView.description hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHostView"]) {
        return superView;
    }else if([superView.description hasPrefix:@"<UIKBInputBackdropView"]) {
        return superView.superview;
    }else {
        for (UIView *subView in superView.subviews) {
            UIView *keyboardHostView = [self getPeripheralHostViewFromView:subView];
            if (keyboardHostView) {
                return keyboardHostView;
            }
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```